# Obtaining session in Hibernate Listener with Spring Integration

Tags: hibernate, events, spring

When Hibernate is used with Spring, making the DAOs extend HibernateDaoSupport provides the getHibernateTemplate() which is used to obtain the session.

When using a Hibernate Event Listener, I am extending the SaveOrUpdateEventListener and so cannot use the getHibernateTemplate() method to obtain Session.

Is there any way to obtain the session via Spring ?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to call `event.getSession()` in the listener?. Since listener is executed in the context of session, you doesn't need to obtain session via Spring.